# TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror, custom-function

I am using Google Apps Script on Google SpreadSheets and I am trying to use split method on a member of my array and I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of undefined.

This is my code:

```
 function myFunction(range) {
  var Ocurrences=[];
  range.forEach(function(row) {
    var tokens=row.toString().split(' ');
    var hour=tokens[4].split(':')[0];
    Ocurrences.push(hour);
  });
  return Ocurrences;
}
```

The normal guess would be that `tokens[4]` is no defined, but I have already tried to read it's value and it IS defined and it IS a string.

Comment: How do you call `myFunction(range)`? Is `range` a range object, an array or another object type?

Comment: I was calling my function from a cell in a google spreadsheet document like this "=myFunction(A1:A)" the problem was that, since there were some blanks cells, some undefined rows reached myFunction and crashed when reached split call.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add those details.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. It was because I was running my code as a google spreadsheets custom function and the range I was giving to it was the whole column (A1:A). But as there was some blank rows in the column which caused some undefined values reached the function without me noticing it.

One solution is to give the exact range of filled rows (A1:A229 in my case).

A better solution is to add a validation for `token[4]` right before the split call to make sure no `undefined` value will pass. This way the function will support an undefined range of cells.

Here is the code I used:

```
function myFunction(range) {
  var Ocurrences=[];
  range.forEach(function(row) {
    var tokens=row.toString().split(' ');
    if(tokens[4]){
      var hour=tokens[4].split(':')[0];
      Ocurrences.push(hour);
    }
  });
  return Ocurrences;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be something going on in your particular environment. Your code, as-is, works for me:

```
console.log(myFunction(["first second third forth 8:25", "first second third forth 5:25"]));

function myFunction(range) {
  var Ocurrences=[];
  range.forEach(function(row) {
    var tokens=row.toString().split(' ');
    var hour=tokens[4].split(':')[0];
    Ocurrences.push(hour);
  });
  return Ocurrences;
}
```

```js
    console.log(myFunction(["first second third forth 8:25", "first second third forth 5:25"]));
    
    function myFunction(range) {
      var Ocurrences=[];
      range.forEach(function(row) {
        var tokens=row.toString().split(' ');
        var hour=tokens[4].split(':')[0];
        Ocurrences.push(hour);
      });
      return Ocurrences;
    }
```

Comment: Yes it was something about the google spreadsheets behavior I didn't consider. I posted which was the error.